# How to unit test a lambda function that includes a dynamoDB query

Tags: unit-testing, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I have a function in my Alexa skill's lambda function that I am trying to do a unit test for using the `aws-lambda-mock-context` node package. The method I am trying to test includes a call to DynamoDB to check if an item exists in my table.

At the moment, my test immediately fails with `CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config`. Following [this blog](https://bytesandbones.wordpress.com/2017/03/29/amazon-alexa-skill-development-hints-for-rookies-like-me/), I tried to manually enter my Amazon IAM credentials into a .aws/credentials file. Testing with the credentials leads to the test running for 30+ seconds before timing out, with no success or fail result from DynamoDB. I am not sure where to go from here.

The function I am looking to unit test looks like this:

```
helper.prototype.checkForItem = function(alexa) {
  var registration_id = 123;
  var params = {
    TableName: 'registrations',
    Key: {
      id: {"N" : registration_id}
    }
  };

  return this.getItemFromDB(params).then(function(data) {
    //...
  }
```

And the call to DynamoDB:

```
helper.prototype.getItemFromDB = function(params) {
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    dynamoDB.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err == null) {
        console.log("fulfilled");
        fulfill(data);
      }
      else {
        console.log("error recieving data " + err);
        reject(null);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SAM Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/test-sam-local.html) to test you lambda:

> AWS SAM is a fast and easy way of deploying your serverless
>   applications, allowing you to write simple templates to describe your
>   functions and their event sources (Amazon API Gateway, Amazon S3,
>   Kinesis, and so on). Based on AWS SAM, SAM Local is an AWS CLI tool
>   that provides an environment for you to develop, test, and analyze
>   your serverless applications locally before uploading them to the
>   Lambda runtime. Whether you're developing on Linux, Mac, or Microsoft
>   Windows, you can use SAM Local to create a local testing environment
>   that simulates the AWS runtime environment. Doing so helps you address
>   issues such as performance. Working with SAM Local also allows faster,
>   iterative development of your Lambda function code because there is no
>   need to redeploy your application package to the AWS Lambda runtime.
>   For more information, see Building a Simple Application Using SAM
>   Local.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do unit testing you can mock dynamo db endpoint using any mocking library like nock, also you can check fiddler request/ response what your app is making to dynamo db endpoint and then accordingly you can troubleshoot.